# How to create an account, and upload an image with that account with imgur

Tags: python, python-requests, imgur

I am designing a python GUI, one of its functions is taking a screenshot, uploading it to Imgur and then getting the URL. Though I am having issues understanding the documentation (especially since it says you need to create an account through the API, but not how to do it.). Would anyone be able to explain how exactly to create an account and then upload an image using it?

Note: I am using PIL to get the screenshots, I would prefer you explain it as code written with the requests library or maybe curl (as that isn't too hard to move to python with requests), and I'll be saving only the refresh token in the program, as it would be hardcoded (But the user can change it) and I don't want the user to authenticate.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Also, I will not use imgurpython as it is outdated.

Comment: [documentation](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest) shows on image how to do it with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)

Comment: you need normal account on Imgur which you use to put images manually - and then you can use API to put images. After loging to normal account you can register your application on https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to create normal account on Imgur.

After loging to normal account you can go to https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient to register application.

It needs application name and email. Type of authorization depends on how you will use it.

[image]

You should get API keys

[image]

Which you can use with API

To get information:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Client-ID f1XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}

#https://i.imgur.com/cvWgXFc.jpg
imageHash = 'cvWgXFc'

r = requests.get(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image/{imageHash}', headers=headers)
print('status:', r.status_code)
data = r.json()

print(data)
print('size:', data['data']['size'])
```

Result:

```
status: 200

{'data': {'id': 'cvWgXFc', 'title': None, 'description': None, 'datetime': 1579572289, 'type': 'image/jpeg', 'animated': False, 'width': 506, 'height': 500, 'size': 89341, 'views': 8087, 'bandwidth': 722500667, 'vote': None, 'favorite': False, 'nsfw': False, 'section': None, 'account_url': None, 'account_id': None, 'is_ad': False, 'in_most_viral': False, 'has_sound': False, 'tags': [], 'ad_type': 0, 'ad_url': '', 'edited': '0', 'in_gallery': False, 'link': 'https://i.imgur.com/cvWgXFc.jpg', 'ad_config': {'safeFlags': ['onsfw_mod_safe', 'share', 'page_load'], 'highRiskFlags': [], 'unsafeFlags': ['not_in_gallery', 'sixth_mod_unsafe'], 'wallUnsafeFlags': [], 'showsAds': False}}, 'success': True, 'status': 200}

size: 89341
```

To upload:

```
import requests
import base64

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Client-ID f1XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}

params = {
  'image': base64.b64encode(open('images.png', 'rb').read())
}

r = requests.post(f'https://api.imgur.com/3/image', headers=headers, data=params)
print('status:', r.status_code)
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

---

**BTW:** you can see your registered applications and regenerate API keys (if you forget it) after login on https://imgur.com/account/settings/apps

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question perfectly!

Comment: I added example to upload image but I didn't check if it add to account or as anonymouse user.

Comment: This method will upload the images to Imgur, but it does not associate them with my account. This is an issue for me because some of my images are over Imgur's 1 MB limit and are converted from .png to .jpg with noticeable compression (e.g. artifacts on text, decreased resolution). If I upload the same image on their website, the limit is 5 MB because it is associated with my account and it is not converted from .png. I tried adding both my Client Secret and Client ID to the header, but that does not resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Imgur API, which you can get from 
[here](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest):
Once you get the API key from their site, you can start writing some code.